# Meaning of multiplication of a function and a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,m)$ be a measure space and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ a non-negative function. What is the precise definition of the measure $fm$? I have tried to look for it but cannot find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $\mu = fm$, this means that for any measurable set $E$,
$$ \mu(E) = \int_E f \ dm.$$
$\mu$ is clearly a measure: $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ is obvious, and countably additivity follows from the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: $f$ should be measurable to do that, right?

Comment: Yeah, $f$ needs to be measurable.

Comment: Does the measure $fm$ have a particular name and is this the standard notation?

Comment: @Filippo I'd say that it is standard. Some terminology: one says that $\mu$ has the density $f$ with respect to $m$. (You probably are familiar with this if $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.)